# Rounded corners for UITabBar

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I would like to create a UITabBar with rounded corners. Is there a way I can make the UITabBar have rounded corners? It would take the shape of the second picture.

The app starts off with a tableView. When the user taps a topic, they are sent to a tabBar controller.

[image]

[image: This is the shape I want it to take]

-----edit-----

This is my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_application: UIApplication,
willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool{

    let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let image = UIImage(named: "bar")
    let tabBarImage = resize(image: image!, newWidth: tabBarController.view.frame.width)
    tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = tabBarImage
    

    return true
}

func resize(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: image.size.height))
image.drawInRect( CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: image.size.height))
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return newImage!
}
```

[image]

Edit: Dec '21
Replaced image to omit name on project.

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I used a simple property of the tabBar which is backgroundImage.

So, I added in the appDelegate in didFinisLaunchingWithOptions:

```
let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let image = UIImage(named: "bar")
    let tabBarImage = resize(image: image!, newWidth: tabBarController.view.frame.width)
    tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = tabBarImage
```

and my custom method to change the size of the image:

```
func resize(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: image.size.height))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: image.size.height)) // image.drawInRect( CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: image.size.height))  in swift 2
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

I used a png image as the background, the same that you posted but with clear color instead of the black color.

Hope this helps

Comment: Also, it says "UIiimage has no member of 'Draw'"

Comment: you should't be getting that error, are you sure you are adding the code in :

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {}

Comment: okay the UIImage one is because I'm using swift3, which version are you using?.

use this in swift 2.2:  image.drawInRect( CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: image.size.height))

Comment: The image one went away. I am in swift 2.2. The window error is still there. Yes. It's in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

Comment: I edited the question so you can see my app delegate

Comment: see just above your comment //NAVIGATION-BAR-COLOR you are closing the appDelegate, delete that bracket and close the bracket at the end of your file.

Comment: Okay so it turns out I wasn't specific enough. The app does not start out in a tab bar controller. It is a view controller that goes into a tab bar controller

Comment: The error cleared up but it crashed because the app itself does not start off on a tab bar controller

Comment: I solved it. It's like your solution, but someone simplified it. still a valid answer.

Comment: Cool... I'm glad it was useful

Answer (score 24):

Hope this help you

```
self.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true 
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true 
self.tabBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque 
self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20 
self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

Comment: this answer saved me after a lot of search!

Answer (score 5):

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 4):

Its working fine for me

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barStyle = .default
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: tabBar.frame.height), cornerRadius: 15)
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    tabBar.layer.mask = mask

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case works this way:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        isTranslucent = true
        barStyle = .blackOpaque
        layer.cornerRadius = 44
        layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }
}
```

Then set class CustomTabBar for TabBar in storyboard:

[image: set class CustomTabBar for TabBar in storyboard]