# How to resize width tabBarController and make its radius

Tags: swift

import UIKit

class Login: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 15
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Apple doesn't make it easy to modify complete components that they provide for you out of the box. So there's no border radius that will be easy to modify in just one line of code. The good news is there are some simple solutions to get similar results to what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127839/rounded-corners-for-uitabbar), involving the background image, and modifying border radius.

If you're okay with doing something custom and crazy, you can try modifying [this](https://gist.github.com/aldo-jlaurenstin/2ed6569b1a3746645143) gist to make an overlay that would "remove" the parts of the tab bar that you're not interested in (by making them transparent), and from there you could modify the dimensions of the buttons to fit in the parts of the tab bar you are interested in. This comes with it's own challenges: how to make a UIView shaped like an arched bridge is a bit beyond my experience.

Good luck!

Comment: I used the first option but I got this crash (Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1f3832280) to 'UITabBarController' (0x1f3832050).)

Answer (score 1):

These Are the Extensions you can use and make radius shadow every thing to buttons views tab bar even to navigation bar just put this code in your class end and on right side in inspector you can see different controllers which can help you :)

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.borderColor = nil
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
}


@IBDesignable extension UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            layer.borderColor = uiColor.cgColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else { return nil }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }
}
```