# Change TabBar mask color (non-transparent)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

I am creating a TabBar with top left and top right corners rounded.

I'm using a layer mask to achieve this and it works fine, however I need the mask color to be white (its transparent showing the VC background color with the below code).

Is it possible to set the mask background color white with below approach?

I've tried setting layer and layer.mask background colours but with no success (I can't change the VC background color).

current code:

```
self.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
self.tabBar.barStyle = .default
self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 28
self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try all the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127839/rounded-corners-for-uitabbar

Comment: My code above is actually taken from the most popular answer on the thread you suggest. My question is can I use this solution to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set background color to layer mask, you need another layer

Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r36Dy.png) the effect you needed?

You may try this:

```
extension UITabBar {

func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, backgroundColor: UIColor, cornerColor: UIColor, radius: Int = 20) {

    self.backgroundColor = cornerColor
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = bounds
    parentLayer.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
    layer.insertSublayer(parentLayer, at: 0)

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = bounds
    mask.path = maskPath.cgPath
    parentLayer.mask = mask
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you have specifically set the mask in your example as white? then yes this would be exactly what I'm after. Not at a computer now but will test later. Thanks.

Comment: I use a workaround approach in my example. Instead of setting mask as white, I set the tab bar as white and insert another colored layer with mask on it. This could make the effect you need.